# Get group members from Azure AD via web activity

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-data-factory, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to fetch list of all members from AD security group through ADF pipeline

I came across this API method: [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/%7Bgroup) id}/members

Can someone help me work out how I can run this API through web activity by ADF pipeline.

Also any permissions or access I need to have before running this API.

Thanks for your help and suggestions

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0), it lists the permissions needed for calling this Graph API.

Comment: yeah i go through them, but i cant understand how and where i can get these permission

Answer (score 3):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I created an **Azure AD Application and granted API permissions** like below:

[image]

**Generate the access token like below by creating the web activity:**

- **URL**:  `https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token`
- **Method :**  POST
- **Body:**  `grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`
- **Header:**  `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

[image]

**I generated access token successfully like below:**

[image]

I created **Azure AD security Group** and added members:

[image]

To fetch list of all members from Azure AD security group, use the query in web activity 2 like below:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/GroupID/members
```

In **Authentication**, use this Dynamic content `Bearer @{activity('Web1').output.access_token}`

[image]

**I am able to fetch list of all members from Azure AD security group successfully like below:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[List group members - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: cool, i will try it right now. Thanks Imran

Comment: i got this errorin web2 activity: "Authorization_RequestDenied","message":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Comment: In Azure Ad make sure to grant admin consent for GroupMember.Read.All api permission

Comment: yes admin consent is granted but still same error

Comment: do you think also need write permission for group, groupmembers and directory ?

Comment: can you confirm whether you are an admin?

Comment: no i am not, i need to raise some ticket to get those access

Comment: Could you decode the token using jwt.ms and check if the GroupMember.Read.All is present?

Comment: yes i can decode the token using jwt.ms and GroupMember.Read.All is also present

Comment: The error usually occurs if the permissions are not been granted to perform the action. I tried to do the same in my environment but it worked for me. Kindly check again and try.

Comment: Can you tell me what permissions you azure ad app have? do we need directory.read.all as well?

Comment: Only GroupMember.Read.All API permission is required to perform the action.